# How to overlay a raster using OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Through the example provided by the examples section of the OpenLayers website I was able to replicate the overlay method of an image. But when I try to add a different raster, now present in the filesystem, I can not get the same result. The format of the raster is in PNG.

I'm trying to do something like this: [openaerialmap.org](https://openaerialmap.org). Where I can overlay my own aerial images above a map (in example is OSM, but I will use Bing Maps in the beggining).

Other similar questions that did not help me:

1. [Using Custom Aerial Raster Imagery with OpenLayers 3 or 4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238675/using-custom-aerial-raster-imagery-with-openlayers-3-or-4)
2. [Raster overlay in OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90958/raster-overlay-in-openlayers)
3. [OpenLayers 4 adding a georeferenced image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250909/openlayers-4-adding-a-georeferenced-image)
4. [How to define layer order in Openlayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15238/how-to-define-layer-order-in-openlayers)

I'm using OpenLayers v5.3

JS code:

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import {getCenter} from 'ol/extent.js';
import {Image as ImageLayer, Tile as TileLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
import {transform} from 'ol/proj.js';
import Static from 'ol/source/ImageStatic.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import {register} from 'ol/proj/proj4.js';
import proj4 from 'proj4';

var imageExtent = [591338.2230843633878976, -3835585.6850060112774372, 591735.8523469158681110, -3834804.7757325535640121];

var map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
    new ImageLayer({
      source: new Static({
        url: "/img/test.png",
        crossOrigin: '',
        projection: 'EPSG:32655',
        imageExtent: imageExtent,
        imageSize: [7953,15619]
      })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [-10997148, 4569099],
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```

Extent from raster was extracted from QGIS

The console shows no error and the image seems to load, but I can't find antwhere in the map.

Comment: If you center the view on one of the image corners (`center: [ 591338, -3835585 ]` in the view definition) do you see the image? If not, try switching coordinates - i always get coordinate order wrong, because it differs between GIS frameworks).
Can you access the image file directly in a browser (via the URL `http(s)://<yourserver, or localhost>/img/test.png`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the projection

```
  proj4.defs('EPSG:32655', '+proj=utm +zone=55 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ');
  register(proj4);
```

Comment: In case anyone wonder, it is possible to get this information from EPSG website, from the export section on the bottom of the webpage. For this example: https://epsg.io/32655. Thanks for the help, Mike ;)

Comment: Yes, you can query that site and get a json response. See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-by-code.html